# How to analyze memcache key hit rate with graphite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphite, statsd

I have a Rails app which uses caching extensively and I want to know cache hit rate for different places in the app. Low hit rate places obviously need attention. But measure first!

To obtain real data I use graphite + statsd combo and a [custom Dalli instrumentation](https://gist.github.com/be9/2034c5b6bfa229682008) employing [statsd-instrument gem](https://github.com/Shopify/statsd-instrument). All keys in the app are in form `['place', details...]`, so I get following metrics in graphite:

- stats.cache.place1.hits
- stats.cache.place1.misses
- stats.cache.place2.hits
- stats.cache.place2.misses
- etc.

Now I want to show all hit rates. I was able to come up with following formula for one place:

```
divideSeries(stats.cache.place1.hits, sumSeries(stats.cache.place1.*))
```

It works quite well, but there are several dozen places and I'd hate to duplicate it, not to mention that new places can appear.

This is a question for you, Graphite experts: is there a way to show hit rates for all places? I've seen group* functions in the docs, but they confuse me.

Ideally I want to segment my places into 4 categories:

- **High hit rate, many requests.** Caching is doing good job.
- **Low hit rate, many requests.** Needs attention.
- **High hit rate, few requests.** Is caching needed at all?
- **Low hit rate, few requests.** Definitely remove caching.

I'd be really grateful for any ideas how to use graphite for such analysis (I can request data in JSON format and do my own math, but I suspect there must be a simpler way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use globs at multiple levels, so for the global view of how all caching is performing:

```
divideSeries(stats.cache.*.hits, sumSeries(stats.cache.*.*))
```

For the 4 categories you mention, [the `mostDeviant` function might be good](http://obfuscurity.com/2012/04/Unhelpful-Graphite-Tip-6), that would help find the highest/lowest cache rates.

```
mostDeviant(5, divideSeries(stats.cache.*.hits, sumSeries(stats.cache.*.*)))
```

To group them into buckets based on requests and then showing a separate derived ratio is harder.   Callback functions using repeated [`groupByNode`](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.groupByNode) and [`highestAverage`](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.highestAverage) might work

```
highestAverage(groupByNode(groupByNode(stats.cache.*.*, 3, "sumSeries"), 2, "divideSeries"), 10)
```

As a side note, with most LRU (least-recently used) cache eviction schemes, there isn't much point in *removing* caching, as it won't compete for cache space.

Comment: Thank you @phillbaker, I mark you answer as accepted, however I went for a simple clojure app which downloads and processes JSON data from graphite.

As for removing caching, I still think it has some sense. See, the whole point of caching is to replace access time **T** (spent on database access or generation of something) with smaller cache access time **t**. However, cache miss results in **T+t** (assuming that cache read and cache write operations are comparable in time). With 100 % cache miss there's no sense to spend this extra *t* at all.